# Semester wise results and display cgpa count by range

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How to calculate grade wise counts by semester and grade range.

I am having tables, fields and data as follows:

**SEMETSER**

| SEMISTER_NO | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FIRST |
| 2 | SECOND |

**STUDENT_SEMETSER**

| STUDENT_NO | SEMESTER_NO | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9.8 |
| 2 | 1 | 9.2 |
| 3 | 1 | 8.8 |
| 4 | 1 | 7.8 |
| 5 | 1 | 7.5 |
| 6 | 1 | 7.2 |
| 7 | 2 | 8.8 |
| 8 | 2 | 8.2 |
| 9 | 2 | 8.8 |
| 10 | 2 | 6.8 |
| 11 | 2 | 6.5 |
| 12 | 2 | 6.2 |

**RESULTS Expected:**

| SEMESTER_NO | SCORE 10-9 | SCORE 9-8 | 8-7 | 7-6 | 6-5 | 5-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: If my understanding is correct, It must be `3` for `score 7-6` in SEMESTER_NO `2`

Comment: Please, for your own sanity, fix typos: it is *semester*, not "sem*i*ster" or "SEME*TS*ER"

Answer (score 1):

Using `CASE-WHEN` and `PIVOT` is one of the options:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT semester_no,
          CASE 
            WHEN SCORE>= 9 and SCORE<=10 THEN 'Score 10-9'
            WHEN SCORE>= 8 and SCORE<9 THEN 'Score 9-8'
            WHEN SCORE>= 7 and SCORE<8 THEN 'Score 8-7'
            WHEN SCORE>= 6 and SCORE<7 THEN 'Score 7-6'
            WHEN SCORE>= 5 and SCORE<6 THEN 'Score 6-5'
            WHEN SCORE>= 4 and SCORE<5 THEN 'Score 5-4'
          END AS score_cat
   FROM student_semester
)
PIVOT 
(
   COUNT(score_cat)
   FOR score_cat IN ('Score 10-9','Score 9-8','Score 8-7','Score 7-6','Score 6-5','Score 5-4')
)
ORDER BY semester_no
```

The `CASE` statement will categorize the score into different buckets *(Modify as per your need)* and `PIVOT` statement will transpose the data into desired level.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f12841cc1e2cf88a2ee896f7015f8e71)

Comment: Do you really have to check for `<=10`? When you have handled `>=9` in the line before, then you don't need to check again for `<9` in the ">=8" line

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Checking for `<9` and others could be avoided. Agreed with you! However, I feel we can still check for `<=10` in first condition because we might not know the actual upper bound of the score. Your thoughts?

Comment: I *expect* scores to be in the 1-10 range, but I may be mistaken in this case.